# Match words and full stops, but not the trailing full stop

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a string of the type `$word1.word2.word3`, which contain dots inside, but should not end with a dot.

In other words:

`$context.abc.value`, `$context.abc.value.random()` - should match full string

`$context.abc.value.` - should match everything except the last character (dot).

My regex for now is:

`(?:^|\s)\$(?!\d)[\w.\[\]\(\)]+`

Here's a fiddle to play with: https://regex101.com/r/PxCtUv/1

How can I avoid matching the trailing dot character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may "decompose" the last `[a.]+` pattern into `[a.]*[a]`:

```
(?:^|\s)\$(?!\d)[\w.[\]()]*[\w[\]()]
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sy1VZS/1).

**Details**

- `(?:^|\s)` - a non-capturing group matching either start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a whitespace (`\s`)
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit right after the `$` char
- `[\w.[\]()]*` - zero or more word, `.`, `[`, `]`, `(` or `)` chars
- `[\w[\]()]` - a  word, `.`, `[`, `]`, `(` or `)` char.

Comment: Note that inside `[...]` (a character class), `[`, `(` and `)` lose their "speial" meaning, and they do not have to be escaped there. It is even treated as an error in ES6 regexps compiled with `u` flag. Also, have a look at [an alternative regex](https://regex101.com/r/Sy1VZS/2). Feel free to precise it further.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following one:

```
\$(?!\d)[\w]+([.]{0,1}[\w()]+)+
```

You can try it the following way: https://regex101.com/r/2ONUHj/1

- This will not match the whitespaces before the `$` sign.
- it will allow only one `.`

There could be a lot of other edge cases not defined here.

For further details use the explanation on https://regexr.com/.

Comment: Interesting. However, note that you left out `[` and `]` that the original regex matched. Your regex can be "tidied up" as `\$[a-zA-Z_]\w*(?:\.[\w()]+)*`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without using regex, if you wanted to:

```
const data = [
    'context.abc.value',
    '$context.abc.value.random()',
    '$context.abc.value.'
];

const filtered = data.filter(item => Array.from(item).pop() !== '.');

// [ 'context.abc.value', '$context.abc.value.random()' ]
```